# How can a multiprocessing pool be set up as a global variable?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to have multiprocessing pools available to multiple methods in multiple files as a global variable.

I have tried this using a setup with 5 files:

- main.py
- pool_settings.py
- population_calculation.py
- individual calculation.py
- inside_of_individual_calculation.py

Here is the code of all files:

**pool_settings.py**

```
numberOfIndividuals = 10
workersPerIndividuals = 5

import multiprocessing as mp

def init():
    global pool
    pool = mp.Pool(numberOfIndividuals)

    global listOfPools
    listOfPools = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfIndividuals):
        listOfPools.append(mp.Pool(workersPerIndividuals))
```

**population_calculation.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pool_settings
import individual_calculation as ic

def calculatePopulation():
    
    results_population = pool_settings.pool.map_async(ic.calculateIndividual, range(0,pool_settings.numberOfIndividuals)).get()
    
    print(results_population)
```

**individual_calculation.py**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import pool_settings
import numpy as np
import inside_of_individual_calculation as ioic

def calculateIndividual(individual):

    data = []

    for i in range(0,pool_settings.workersPerIndividuals):
        data.append(np.random.rand(100))
        
    results_individual = pool_settings.listOfPools[mp.current_process()._identity[0]-1].map_async(ioic.calculateInsideIndividual,data).get()
    
    return sum(results_individual)
```

**inside_of_individual_calculation.py**

```
import numpy as np

def calculateInsideIndividual(individualRow):
    return individualRow.sum()
```

**main.py**

```
import pool_settings
import population_calculation
pool_settings.init()
population_calculation.calculatePopulation()
```

When I run main.py (>>>python main.py) I get the following error:
"AttributeError: module 'pool_settings' has no attribute 'listOfPools'"

I have tried multiple ways and I always get the same error. How can I set up a multiprocessing pool as a global variable so that it is accessible to multiple methods in multiple files?

Thanks a lot,
Joe

P.S.: I also tried a multiprocessing pool in which each process would spin up another multiprocessing pool, and didn't work either

Comment: You need to pass the `pool` parameter to all the functions that need it.  Python does not have globals that cross between files.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried that and got an error stating that pool objects can not be passed as parameters. I have also made global variables (in general, not multiprocessing objects) work across files. Not sure why I am getting those errors...

Comment: I created a simpler version of what you have with just the main script and one imported module that is essentially your *pool_settings.py* and the main script had no problem accessing either `pool` or `listOfPools`, which by the way you are *not* accessing in the code you posted. This works in both Linux and Windows (although for Windows you need in *main.py* to but the call to `pool_settings.init()` in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block).

Answer (score 0):

You may change `pool_settings.py` like:

```py
numberOfIndividuals = 10
workersPerIndividuals = 5

import multiprocessing as mp

def init():
    pool = mp.Pool(numberOfIndividuals)

    global listOfPools
    listOfPools = []
    for i in range(0,numberOfIndividuals):
        listOfPools.append(mp.Pool(workersPerIndividuals))
    return pool, listOfPools

pool, listOfPools = init()
```

1. That will allow to use `from pool_settings import pool` or `import pool_settings; pool_settings.pool`
2. `pool` and `listOfPools` will be automatically initialized on first `pool_settings` import (instead of manually calling `pool_settings.init()`)